# Bash Shell Scripting - detect the Enter key

Tags: bash, shell, string-comparison, enter

I need to compare my input with <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> key...

```
read -n1 key
if [ $key == "\n" ]
   echo "@@@"
fi
```

But this is not working.. What is wrong with this code

Comment: You're missing "then" on the line between "if" and "echo".  Not the only problem, but one

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Several issues with the posted code.  Inline comments detail what to fix:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# ^^ Bash, not sh, must be used for read options

read -s -n 1 key  # -s: do not echo input character. -n 1: read only 1 character (separate with space)

# double brackets to test, single equals sign, empty string for just 'enter' in this case...
# if [[ ... ]] is followed by semicolon and 'then' keyword
if [[ $key = "" ]]; then 
    echo 'You pressed enter!'
else
    echo "You pressed '$key'"
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If you press ESC it goes to "You presesed enter!"

Comment: @Jiu, seems that you're using `sh file` to execute it rather than `bash file` or just `./file` if it has `chmod +x file`. I would remark that Googling is far away faster than wrote such comment.

Comment: @BrunoMedina. Well, if you use raw option `-r` you'll read `""` for Return key and `"\e"` for escape key, making a difference between them. Using the current `read -s -n` will strip out backslashed's, making both as `""`. So, just `read -r -s -n 1 key` will solve.

Answer (score 8):

Also it is good idea to define empty $IFS (internal field separator) before making comparisons, because otherwise you can end up with " " and "\n" being equal.

So the code should look like this:

```
# for distinguishing " ", "\t" from "\n"
IFS=

read -n 1 key
if [ "$key" = "" ]; then
   echo "This was really Enter, not space, tab or something else"
fi
```

Comment: #this does not work for me if using loop printing coutdown
IFS=
echo -e "Press [ENTER] For Keyboard Configuration."
for (( i=10; i>0; i--)); do
printf "\rStarting in $i seconds..."
read -n 1 -t 1 key
if [ "$key" = $'\e' ]; then
       echo "This is ESC"
        break
elif [ "$key" == "" ] ;then
        echo -e "\n space is pressed"
        break
fi
done

Comment: maybe the thing is that for inline syntax you should use IFS=; echo... (with semicolon)

Comment: Pretty nice fix just using `IFS=`

Comment: Doesn't this change the behavior of the rest of the script?

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding below code just for reference if someone will want to use such solution containing countdown loop.

```
IFS=''
echo -e "Press [ENTER] to start Configuration..."
for (( i=10; i>0; i--)); do

printf "\rStarting in $i seconds..."
read -s -N 1 -t 1 key

if [ "$key" = $'\e' ]; then
        echo -e "\n [ESC] Pressed"
        break
elif [ "$key" == $'\x0a' ] ;then
        echo -e "\n [Enter] Pressed"
        break
fi

done
```

Comment: This fit perfectly into a while loop, so that I could execute something while I wait. :D

Answer (score 4):

`read` reads a line from standard input, up to but not including the new line at the end of the line.  `-n` specifies the maximum number of characters, forcing `read` to return early if you reach that number of characters.  It will still end earlier however, when the <kbd>Return</kbd> key is pressed.  In this case, its returning an empty string - everything up to but not including the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

You need to compare against the empty string to tell if the user immediately pressed <kbd>Return</kbd>.

```
read -n1 KEY
if [[ "$KEY" == "" ]]
then
  echo "@@@";
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these conditions worked for me and so I've came up with this one:

```
${key} = $'\0A'
```

Tested on CentOS with Bash 4.2.46.

Comment: It works! After trying with [[ $key == $'\x0A' ]] but did not works, changed it to $'\0a', now works. Tested on Arch with Bash 5.1

Comment: `00 0A` is ASCII for `LF`. Unicode [`\x000A`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+000A) may eventually work, too.